# Is possible exists a injective function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x^2)-f(f(x))\geq 1/4$?

Tags: functions, inequality

> Is possible exists a injective function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x^2)-f(f(x))\geq 1/4$?

Anyone can give a tip? It's an exercise about *functional equations*.

Comment: You do not require $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: Don't. In the list of exercises it is written like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. Consider $f(x) = x - 1$. Then

$f(x^2) - f(f(x)) = (x^2 - 1) - ((x - 1) - 1) = x^2 - x + 1 = (x - \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{3}{4} \geq \frac{3}{4} \geq \frac{1}{4}$.